# Probability that random walkers meet

Tags: probability, random-walk

I was wondering about a question about Random Walks. I came across various papers where the probability of 2 random walkers in 1 dimension and 2 dimension starting at the same point and returning to the origin was found. I was doing a research on a question similar to this - What is the probability that 2 random walkers, originating from the same point, meet at a point other than the origin?

I tried solving the cases for 1 dimension and 2 dimension but I was stuck because the displacement does not become 0 in this case. I couldn't handle the displacement term. I would be glad if someone could give me some hint or tell me how I should proceed further.

Comment: Random walks in how many dimensions?

Comment: Random walks in 1d and 2d

Comment: It's still unclear to me what the question is. Did you figure out 1D and need a pointer for 2D? Do you need both? If both, maybe just ask about one first, then once you know a little more about asking good questions, ask about the other problem.

Comment: I got 1D. I need a hint for 2D.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $1D$ random walk:

For the two random walkers($W_1, W_2$) to meet at some time point $N$, the number of left steps taken by $W_1$ should equal the number of steps taken by $W_2$

The number of sequences of lefts and rights possible for each walker is $2^N$.

Now, in order for $W_1$ and $W_2$ to meet, they must have taken $0\ or\ 1\ or\ 2\ or\ 3\ or\ \ldots \ N $ left steps, which can be done in:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{N} \frac{\binom{N}{i}\binom{N}{i}}{2^N2^N} = \frac{\binom{2N}{N}}{4^N}
$$

Comment: btw, W_1 is outside of the math enviroment

Comment: The final formula is direct if one notices that one asks for the steps of the first walker minus the steps of the second walker to lead to the initial point, or equivalently, that one single walker is again at its starting point after 2N steps.

Comment: "Meet at some time point N", what do you mean by time point?

Comment: So this is the probability that 2 random walkers, both originating from the same point, meet at a point other than the origin?

Comment: Yes. They need to be 'at the same point' when meeting. This should answer your previous question too.

Comment: So the probability of 2 random walkers originating from the same origin and meeting at a point other than the origin is same as the probability of them meeting back at the origin?